# Add button inside form in Filamentphp v2

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

Have you tried creating a form in filamentphp with button inside it? I want to add button inside the field set and it's function is to clear the radio button.

What I have in my form is a field set and inside it there are 3 radio button.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can always add a formAction field which has an action button that can access other fields using the $get and $get

```
        Forms\Components\Actions::make([
            Forms\Components\Actions\Action::make('button name')
              ->action(function (Forms\Get $get, Forms\Set $set) {
                  $result = 'do something'
                  $set('anotherfield', $result);
             })
        ]),
```